# Wordpress 3.8 image path to image folder not working

Tags: php, wordpress, image, filepath

This seems to have been asked around, but with different answers.

I've the image folder "**images**" in the same directory as the **page.php** file which I want to add images to. Yet the path "**images/foldername/image.gif**" doesn't yield any images on the page. Whereas from a non-wordpress html file that path would work, so what is the answer to this? What makes wordpress not understand file paths, assuming I'm not missing something?

also tried /images with the slash just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
echo get_bloginfo('template_url') . 'images/imagename.png';
```

Or

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/img.png" />
```

[bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo), [get bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo). Also, read [this article](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/06/relative-urls.html).

Answer (score 0):

You mean inside the WordPress themes folder? If so, correct path is `http://www.domain.com/subdirectory/wp-content/themes/yourtheme_name/images`

You can use  `<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/foldername/image.gif`

[get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

Comment: Yes inside the theme folder. Both page.php and the images folder are in the same directory not sure why images/imagename.gif wouldn't work. But now I just need to know how to reference images from the styles.css which is also in the same directory, as I think php doesn't work within css files.

Comment: `images/image.gif` is relative to your current page or post (`http://domain.com/my_page`). theme's stylesheet should be in your theme's folder. if your images in the images folder, then you can call files as `images/image.png`